# How to use different UserControls(are declared in ResourceDictionary) in HeaderedItemsControl?

Tags: wpf, resourcedictionary, headereditemscontrol

I have user `HeaderedItemsControl` to display different `UserControl` in my application.
Now I declared these `UserControl` with `DataTemplate` as follows in my `MainWindow`.

```
<HeaderedItemsControl.Resources>
       <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:SearchViewModel}">
             <vw:SearchStudentView/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:SearchViewModel2}">
             <vw:SearchStudentView2/>
        </DataTemplate>
</HeaderedItemsControl.Resources>
```

But I have almost 20 view and I want to place all `DataTemplate` in `ResourceDictionary`.
Can any one help me how can I use these `DataTemplate`'s from `ResourceDictionary` in `HeaderedItemsControl`'s resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very simple.

1) You must create and add `DataTemplate` to `ResourceDictionary`.

2) In App.xaml file you must add created `ResoueceDictionary` (*TemplateResourceDictionary.xaml* is my test `ResourceDictionary`).

```
<Application x:Class="ResourceDictionaryExample.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="TemplateResourceDictionary.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

That's all. :)

Comment: Its Works perferctly for me. thanx for your kind help...:)